# JQuery datepicker closes when changing month in IE8

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have an issue with a jQuery date picker which will work fine in Chrome or in IE9, however in IE8, it will close whenever someone clicks on the month selection dropdown, it closes when hovered over the months list but the year dropdown works fine for all browsers.I am using 1.11 version of jquery.ui

Comment: Can you please isolate your problem into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Typically the datepicker can be flaky when your using a particular date format that isn't supported. Setup a fiddle and you'll likely get an answer quickly.

Comment: @James fiddle doesnt seem to work in is properly. so not able to setup a fiddle

Comment: Did you include jQuery UI into your fiddle? On the left hand side you need to also include what JS libraries your code depends on. Such as jQuery and jQueryUI.